# I accidentally touched my rMBP screen with sweaty hands

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

So I accidentally touched my rMBP screen , I have to admit that my hands were a bit sweaty when I touched it, I immediately took a microfiber cloth and cleaned  the screen, did I caused any damage to it?

Comment: Probably not, however without physically examining the screen and seeing it under use there is no way for anyone but yourself to know.  Maybe you could have rubbed it to hard or the cloth had grit on it and scratched the screen, etc... how could we realistically answer such a question sight unseen!? (Rhetorical question, so no need to reply.)

Answer (score 1):

No, especially not if you cleaned it immediately. You have nothing to worry about.